# Добавить новые поля при редактировании профиля C# .net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, asp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Доброго времени суток всем! У меня такой вопрос: на asp .net mvc создаю веб приложение, регистрация проходит с помощью логина, почты и пароля. После регистрации и входа в аккаунт в личном кабинете можно добавлять информацию о себе (на данный момент планирую добавить только имя и фамилию, но пока что не получается). В интернете искал об этом инфу, но больше половины ответов это о том, как добавить имя и другие поля ПРИ регистрации (а мне надо именно, чтобы после регистрации в личном кабинете). Снизу скидываю то, как я начал, подскажите пожалуйста что надо доделать и исправить)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавить 2 поля в класс - это не начало. Также как описание вашей задачи не является проблемой. Мы тут решаем проблемы людей, например если программист работает над задачей, но не может решить конкретную проблему, но может о ней рассказать максимально подробно. Решайте свои задачи сами или пишите что конкретно у вас не получается, что вы пробовали и какой результат ваших попыток получили.

Comment: Лучше вместо кода на картинке, приводить код текстом, чтобы его легче было воспроизводить

Comment: В метод EditProfile добавил:
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName };
                var result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }
            return View(model);
В итоге при редактировании выдает: Name не может иметь значение NULL или быть пустым.

Comment: Так то зачем? `var user = new ApplicationUser { FirstName = model.FirstName, LastName = model.LastName };` - у вас юзер только из имени и фамилии состоит? А где остальные поля?

Comment: Остальные поля я же при регистрации заполнил, я сейчас всего лишь дополняю инфу о юзере. Если код не правильный, как можно исправить?

Comment: Я конечно не спец, но вот тут `var result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);` вы по сути передаете просто класс с заполненными именем и фамилией, как система вообще поймет, которого юзера вам надо обновить? Как это вижу я: чтобы обновить юзера, надо сначала получить юзера из БД, изменить нужные в ем поля и после сохранить изменения.

Comment: Вставьте код текстом, скрины кода не приветствуются на этом сайте.